# How to subscribe an dijit event in the JS code?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I am new to the Dojo framework, and try to subscribe an onChange event for a ComboBox Dijit in the code grammatically. But for some reason, my event handler function can't catch this event. Could you help me to find out where am I wrong?

```
    <div id="container" style="padding: 5px;">
        <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"     name="state" id="stateInput">                
            <option>Apples</option>
            <option selected>Oranges</option>
            <option>Pears</option>
        </select>           
    </div>




    require([   'dijit/form/ComboBox',  
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/registry"    
    ], function(ComboBox, on,registry){
        var comboBoxDigit2 = registry.byId("stateInput");
        on(comboBoxDigit2,"onChange", function (e) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
    });    
});
```

[Code is here on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lwconquer/vdmhU/12/)

Thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in this code.

1. require passes the array to function in the same order. You are currently passing "dojo/on" and "dijit/registry" into ComboBox, on, and registry. You need to require "dijit/form/ComboBox"
2. The format for data-dojo-type should be a path ie `data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"`
3. The format for on is typically `on(element, eventname, function)` although I believe you can do it the way you are doing it.

Edit:

on works with the event ie

```
on(combobox, "change", function(value) {...});
```

You original fiddle was not being parsed as a dijit, it was just a plain html select, so the call to registry was failing. I've updated the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/vdmhU/13/

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I changed the code as you suggested, but the event handler still doesn't work. Have any other ideas?

Comment: @lwconquer, your combobox was not being parsed into a dijit, I have updated the fiddle

Comment: Many thanks, Matt. It works now. You have a great day. -Wei   http://jsfiddle.net/vdmhU/14/